# Download Plugins from p2 update site without using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, download, repository, p2

I'd like to retrieve the content of an update site. I tried the general way ("Help -> Install New Software"), but unfortunately I can't download the content because of conflicting dependencies. Is it possible to download the content of that repository manually, so that I can work with the plugins myself?

Comment: Most Eclipse plugins can be installed manually by copying the jar files into the plugins directory of the Eclipse. Use google to search for official site of the plugin and download required files. You will need to restart eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a local copy of a remote p2 repository with the p2 mirroring tool. You can call that tool

- [as Eclipse application](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring),
- [as Ant task](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ant_Tasks), or
- [as Maven goal](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Additional_Tools#mirror_goal).

Answer (score 0):

To create a local mirror of an Eclipse update site you may want to try the **B3 Aggregator**, https://www.eclipse.org/b3/.

It comes with an Eclipse editor for specifying the features/bundles to mirror from which update sites.